# Using --trace-stack as argument to xidel

Tags: json, cmd, xidel

I'm getting an error from the following request

```
@ECHO OFF
"H:\Xidel\Xidel.exe" --input-format json-strict -s "H:\ICA\PRIV.JSON\JSON_FORMATTED\JPB113_SWAGGER.JSON" -e "count($json)" 1>NUL 2>"H:\A_MS_exe\json_format_results.txt"
```

The results shown in 'json_format_results.txt' are

```
Error:
jerr:JNDY0021: error at (tkCurlyBraceClose) in }
Possible backtrace:
$005384C6: perhaps Q{http://jsoniq.org/functions}object + 2054 ? but unlikely
$004360FA: perhaps ? ? but unlikely
$00436176: perhaps ? ? but unlikely
$00437DAF: perhaps ? ? but unlikely
$00435544: perhaps ? ? but unlikely
$00435090: perhaps ? ? but unlikely
$0043F2B0: perhaps ? ? but unlikely

Call xidel with --trace-stack to get an actual backtrace
```

If I change the request to

```
@ECHO OFF
"H:\Xidel\Xidel.exe" --trace-stack --input-format json-strict -s "H:\ICA\PRIV.JSON\JSON_FORMATTED\JPB113_SWAGGER.JSON" -e "count($json)" 1>NUL 2>"H:\A_MS_exe\json_format_results.txt"
```

(as I imagine it should be), I only get

```
Error: jerr:JNDY0021: error at  (tkCurlyBraceClose) in }
```

which is less than I would have expected (seeing as how trace is "supposed to be on").
What am I doing wrong with my call?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `count($json)` doesn't make sense as it would always return `1`. Do you really need `--input-format=json-strict`? How does your JSON look like? We're going to need some information.

Comment: Thank you Reino, and thank you (?) for cleaning up the append. I tried using quotes/code but it just turned out a mess. To your questions. The count($json) was suggested here https://sourceforge.net/p/xidel/discussion/help/thread/8312ddcf43/?limit=25#4848. Happy to add the JSON, but how do I do that considering I now have 240-250 chars left in my reply?

Comment: Oh, now I see. Somewhere before _a_ closing `}` there's an error. Your JSON is (probably) prettified, so `xidel` can't show you where the error is exactly. You have to find the error yourself. Or edit your question and add the JSON (as a code-block), or preferably a small as possible excerpt of your JSON that produces the same error. The 240-250 chars left you mentioned apply to your comment, not your question.

Comment: Thank you Reino. Your comment about the prettifying is interesting inasmuch as I never actually look at the results from Xidel. I'm only interested as to whether the generated Json is correct or not. I'll try without the prettify option, but, having said that  ...... WHICH one is it? -s or -e. As I'm writing this append, I'm googling like mad for a list of the Xidel parms such as these two, but I can't find them anywhere (obviously (?) looking wrongly)

Comment: Okay - managed to add the JSON source to my original append. As you might see, I've deliberately added a comma after the closing ] in the required tags. What is "annoying" about this is that various "prettifiers" such as Notepad++, Plugins, Json viewer, Format Json remove this automatically. https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ does not, but says at the same time that the Json code is valid. Xidel doesn't like it (probably because of the json-strict parm ?). When I tried the following variation .....

Comment: "H:\Xidel\Xidel.exe" --trace-stack --input-format json-strict "H:\ICA\PRIV.JSON\JSON_FORMATTED\JPB113_SCHEMA_RESPONSE.JSON" -e "count($json)" 1>NUL 2>"H:\A_MS_exe\json_format_results.txt" I got this in format_results**** Retrieving: H:\ICA\PRIV.JSON\JSON_FORMATTED\JPB113_SCHEMA_RESPONSE.JSON ****
**** Processing: H:\ICA\PRIV.JSON\JSON_FORMATTED\JPB113_SCHEMA_RESPONSE.JSON ****
Error:
jerr:JNDY0021: error at  (tkCurlyBraceClose) in                 }  which didn't help much (all it SEEMS to do is add a couple of lines about where the source code being used is)

Comment: Okay, slightly MORE confused than when I started. Here's my latest call, NOTE THAT I'M EXPERIMENTING WITH THE VARIATIONS I CAN THINK OF (pity you can't add code/quotes in a reply in Stackoverflow or a new line)    "H:\Xidel\Xidel.exe" "H:\ICA\PRIV.JSON\JSON_FORMATTED\JPB113_SCHEMA_RESPONSE.JSON" 1>"H:\A_MS_exe\XIDEL_results.TXT" 2>"H:\A_MS_exe\json_format_results.txt" and the closing lines in json_format_results are "required": [ "consent_id", "consent_ref",  "account_number", "purpose", "product" ],  } [<- error occurs before here]  
              } 
            } 
}

Comment: You *can* add in-line code in comments, as you can see in my previous comments, but that's about it. StackOverflow comments aren't meant for long discussions though, so I suggest you head over to Xidel's forum or mailinglist. But uh... if you deliberately invalidate your JSON, what did you expect from `xidel` with `--input-format=json-strict` other then an error?